# how to retrieve the first inserted record in My sql for particular id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to retrieve the first inserted record in My sql for particular id

For example the ID 102 has three records and i have to retrieve the first inserted record

table name:

### master

### columns and data:

### auto_id #### report_id #### slabs_remaining

---

- 1----------------------1----------------------------55
- 2----------------------1----------------------------54
- 3----------------------1----------------------------53
- 4----------------------2----------------------------100
- 5----------------------2----------------------------99
- 6----------------------1----------------------------52
- 7----------------------1----------------------------51
- 8----------------------3----------------------------200
- 9----------------------3----------------------------199

Now from the above data how to retrieve 1st inserted report_id = 2

Comment: What is your SQL Structure.. Because you can't have three Primary Keys the same.

Comment: This question is asked every 2 or 3 minutes in this SO. Try browsing some recent questions.

Comment: I think you can't unless you've something to identify first inserted record.

Answer (score 2):

use `MIN` and `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT ParticularID, MIN(ID) AS FirstID
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY ParticularID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2466/1)
- [MySQL GROUP BY with some Aggregate Function included](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Example Data

```
╔══════════════╦════╗
║ PARTICULARID ║ ID ║
╠══════════════╬════╣
║            1 ║  1 ║  << First ID
║            1 ║  2 ║
║            1 ║  3 ║
║            2 ║  4 ║  << First ID
║            2 ║  5 ║
║            2 ║  6 ║
║            3 ║  7 ║  << First ID
║            3 ║  8 ║
╚══════════════╩════╝
```

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════════╦═════════╗
║ PARTICULARID ║ FIRSTID ║
╠══════════════╬═════════╣
║            1 ║       1 ║
║            2 ║       4 ║
║            3 ║       7 ║
╚══════════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a combination of ORDER BY *the-id-or-age-of-record* and LIMIT 1 in your query...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, here we are using variables and assuming you only have `particularid` and other columns. Still it's pretty ambiguous to say without seeing your table strucuture..

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef4eb/1)

Table:

```
| PARTICULARID | COL2 |
-----------------------
|            1 |    a |
|            1 |    d |
|            1 |    y |
|            2 |    p |
|            2 |    c |
|            2 |    d |
|            3 |    e |
|            3 |    f |


set @vid:=0;
set @r:=0;

select particularID, col2
from (
SELECT @r:=(case when @vid = ParticularID
then @i + 1 else 1 end) as row,
@vID:=ParticularID, ParticularID, col2 
FROM   tableName
ORDER BY ParticularID) x
where x.row is not null
;


| PARTICULARID | COL2 |
-----------------------
|            1 |    a |
|            2 |    p |
|            3 |    e |
```

Comment: @user1965856 please give this a try and comment.. I assume that you do not have a uniqu identifier column to find which is the first row.. also assume these records are added one after the other... `order by` caluse is essential in this solution.